# Importing WP settings to another host

Tags: options

I am doing development and testing of a WordPress site on my local machine and have tweaked the WP settings accordingly using the GUI.

Installation of WP on my host is easy however, I do not want to go through the GUI and setup everything from the beginning and would like to just import the settings from my local machine.

I know that there is an import/export function in WP but this is only for importing and exporting WP content not WP settings.

So what would be the best method to import the settings.

Thanks in advance.

nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps:

1. Copy/Move all files to new location
2. Export database from old mysql server and import data in new server (you can use phpmyadmin for that)
3. Select wp_options table using phpmyadmin from new location.
4. Edit 2 entry in option table with option name home and siteurl . set option value = new location url
5. Login to wp-admin.
6. Go to setting >> Permalink and update permalink structure if you were using that on old location
7. And you're done. Your new site is live now.

Source: http://wpeden.com/tipsntuts/moving-wordpress-to-new-locationserver-from-an-old-locationserver/

Comment: MIght need to edit wp-config.php if your old/new mysql host/user/PW aren't identical as well

Comment: Thank you for the steps above. Now I have an action plan. :-)